# How to calculate the precise displacement of an object in projectile motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, drag

I am curious about how to calculate the precise location of a projectile.

Assuming that acceleration due to gravity is $-9.81 \text{ms}^{-2}$, how would you calculate the displacement of a tennis ball including drag. Given the angle $\theta$, the initial velocity $v$, and a vertical distance d, from ground level.
Given are the following-

- Drag coefficient of a tennis ball $= 0.50 (\pm 0.05)$ [undergoing turbulent flow]
- Radius of a ball $= 0.067\pm 0.02\ \text m$
- Density of Air $= 1.2\pm0.2\ \text{kgm}^3$
- Mass $= 0.06\pm 0.02\ \text{kg}$

And any other necessary assumptions.

How would you calculate the displacement given that ground level is slanted up or downwards at an angle of $\theta$.

Comment: A full derivation is found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Trajectory_of_a_projectile_with_air_resistance , for $F_D=-kv$.

Answer (score 1):

One could solve Newton's equations with drag:
$$m\ddot{\mathbf{r}} = \mathbf{F}_{drag}(\mathbf{v}) + \mathbf{F}_{gravity}.$$
The drag force is typically directed opposite to the velocity and proportional to its magnitude:
$$\mathbf{F}_{drag}(\mathbf{v}) = -\frac{\mathbf{v}}{v}F_{drag}(v).
$$
The simplest model with $F_{drag}(v) = \nu v$ is definitely solvable, since it produces a set of linear differential equations. I deliberately do not spell it in terms of coordinates, since in case of an inclined surface one may prefer to work in coordinates where x-axis is parallel to the surface.